# splitting input string in sql and getting its value from another table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table hobby and another table hobbyValue.

```
 Hobby Table
 ===========
 hobbies (It is a list of hobbies which user has inserted using checkbox. It gets stores hobby as Ids with a delimiter ^ for e.g hobbyId1^hobbyId2^hobbyId3^)


Hobby Value Table (it has two columns id, Value)
============
hobbyId1 | Football
hobbyId2 | baseball
hobbyId3 | chess
```

I am restricted to use this kind of table format because it is part of a big application. I am not sure how can I write a sql function where input string is hobbies from Hobby table and out put will be its values.

```
 for e.g.
 ============================
 string inputHobbies = hobbies from Hobby table , hobbyId1^hobbyId2^hobbyId3^
 outputValues = input my_sql_function(inputHobbies)

 outputValues should be football,baseball,chess
```

I dont even know how should I start for to get this.

Comment: Storing data like that will only cause you lots of trouble...

Comment: we have predefined architecture , so I can not change that at this point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you will need some string split capability. If you are on Sql Server 2016+, there should be built in `STRING_SPLIT` function (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql).

If not, you can use one below, which I've got some time ago from another SO question.

```
CREATE FUNCTION fnc_splitstring ( @stringToSplit VARCHAR(MAX) )
RETURNS
 @returnList TABLE ([Name] [nvarchar] (500))
AS
BEGIN

 DECLARE @name NVARCHAR(255)
 DECLARE @pos INT

 WHILE CHARINDEX('^', @stringToSplit) > 0
 BEGIN
  SELECT @pos  = CHARINDEX('^', @stringToSplit)  
  SELECT @name = SUBSTRING(@stringToSplit, 1, @pos-1)

  INSERT INTO @returnList 
  SELECT @name

  SELECT @stringToSplit = SUBSTRING(@stringToSplit, @pos+1, LEN(@stringToSplit)-@pos)
 END

 INSERT INTO @returnList
 SELECT @stringToSplit

 RETURN
END
```

Then you can split your hobby ids and join them onto the `Hobby` table, get the actual name and `STUFF` the results into a single result row again:

```
CREATE FUNCTION fnc_getHobbies (@listOfHobbyIds NVARCHAR(MAX))
RETURNS NVARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN 
    DECLARE @hobbies NVARCHAR(MAX)
    SELECT @hobbies = STUFF((   SELECT ',' + hobby
            FROM dbo.fnc_splitstring(@listOfHobbyIds) hb
            INNER JOIN hobby h on h.id = hb.name
            FOR XML PATH('')
            ), 1, 1, '')
    RETURN @hobbies
END
```

End usage like below:

```
SELECT dbo.fnc_getHobbies(hobbyids)
FROM hobbies
```

Lastly, here is the SQL Fiddle for this: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/44cd9

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[SplitForDelimiter] -- a table-valued function
(    
      @delimiter VARCHAR(10),
      @input VARCHAR(1000)

)
RETURNS @tempTable TABLE(
data VARCHAR(100)
)
BEGIN

DECLARE @tempstr VARCHAR(1000)
SET @tempstr = @input
WHILE(charindex(@delimiter,@tempstr,0) > 0)
BEGIN
      DECLARE @t VARCHAR(100)
      SET @t = Substring(@tempstr,0,(charindex(@delimiter,@tempstr,0)))
      INSERT into @tempTable (data) VALUES (@t)
      SET @tempstr = Substring(@tempstr,charindex(@delimiter,@tempstr,0)+1,Len(@tempstr))
      if(charindex(@delimiter,@tempstr,0) <=0)
      BEGIN
      INSERT into @tempTable (data) VALUES (@tempstr)
      END
END
```

Then

```
SELECT Value from HobbyValue HV 
WHERE ID IN (select * from SplitForDelimiter('^','hobbyId1^hobbyId2^hobbyId3^'))
```